# Javascript timeout can't catch the value in class

Tags: javascript, timeout

```
function MyClass(){
  this.field1 = "Field in MyClass";
}

MyClass.prototype.print = function() {
  console.log("print in MyClass:" + this.field1);
}

function useMyClassPrint() {
  var mc = new MyClass();
  mc.print(); 
  setTimeout(mc.print, 10);
  setTimeout("mc.print()", 10);
}
```

I get these results:

```
mc.print(); // this one is easy, it returns "print in MyClass:Field in MyClass"  
// but ...  
setTimeout(mc.print, 10); // "print in MyClass:undefined" why?!  
setTimeout("mc.print()", 10); // runtime error?!@@
```

Comment: because of `this`

Comment: @JaromandaX can you explain in detail? also, how to fix?

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {mc.print();}, 10);` or `setTimeout(mc.print.bind(mc), 10);`

Comment: as for the `"mc.print()"` version ... just don't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function MyClass(){
  this.field1 = "Field in MyClass";
}

MyClass.prototype.print = function() {
  console.log("print in MyClass:" + this.field1);
}

  var mc = new MyClass();
  mc.print(); /*ok*/
  setTimeout(mc.print, 10); /*it's just a reference to function*/
  setTimeout(mc.print.bind(mc),10);/*binded*/
```

When you define

```
function MyClass(){
  this.field1 = "Field in MyClass";
}
```

the field1 is seted when you instantiate the class. field 1 is not a constant.

Try in console:

```
MyClass.field1 -> /*undefined*/

new MyClass().field1 -> /*Field in MyClass*/
```

The setInterval() Function receives a Function:

```
setTimeout(mc.print, 10);
```

mc.print is just a reference to a function, has no reference to your "mc" instance.